# Ограничение на домен

Tags: php, zend-framework

Помогите пожалуйста я написал не большую панельку и мои друзья берут её в аренду, платят мне по 100 рублей в месяц я её закодировал но есть проблема они ставят её куда хотят вот хотел спросить у вас, можно как то сделать ограничение на домен, я написал обновление большое для неё и не хочу её раздавать у меня есть свой личный сайт например

> "site.ru"

могу ли я сделать вот так:
    Я в нём создал папку lic в ней 1 файл txt, вот путь

> "http://site.ru/lic/lic.txt"

Вот если нет данного домена в этом блокноте то при установке ему будет писать купите лицензию

Comment: Извините, но давать в общий доступ список всех лицензий - верх маразма :)

Лучше делать наоборот, скрипт шлет на ваш сервер свою лицензию, а ваш сервер определяет валидная эта лицензия или нет, и в зависимости от этого выдавать сообщение иил нет

Comment: А нет php примеров на файлах для теста ?!

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но реально надежного способа нет: подделать можно все что угодно.
Смысл в том, чтобы при помощи любой функции шифрования с известным только вам и панельке ключом закодировать домен и переслать его. Ваш сайт получает сообщение, сравнивает с тем откуда оно пришло и с таблицей оплаченных версий, кодирует ответ(например, ключ для расшифровки основной функции) и присылает его обратно.
Усложнять можно до бесконечности.

Comment: А нет php примеров на файлах для теста ?!

Comment: Есть, но они платные. >:)

Comment: На самом деле, без стеба. Примерно таким образом была организована "защита" одного из движков. Полный код, по очевидным причинам предложить не могу, а частичный - писать заново. Попробуйте самостоятельно, после чего задайте конкретные вопросы.